# How to merge two nested associative array with same indexes?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with same indexes, and unfortunately array_merge_recursive doesn't work for me.

First array is like this:

```
$firstarray = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Smith'),
    1 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane Doe')         
);
```

Where second array is:

```
$secondarray = array(
    0 => array('email' => 'john@smith.com'),
    1 => array('email' => 'jane@doe.com')
);
```

Desired output would be like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John Smith
            [email] => john@smith.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [email] => jane@doe.com
        )

)
```

But I am getting second array items appended to original array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Jane Doe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => john@smith.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => jane@doe.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Refer to manual: `If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.`

Comment: So, either use string keys or write you own merge function.

Comment: Exactly, I overlooked same numeric key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($firstarray); $i++){
   $output[] = array_merge($firstarray[$i],$secondarray[$i]);
}
```

You can the above mentioned code or you can use array_map() & array_merge().
Like:

```
$output = array_map('array_merge', $firstarray, $secondarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You guys sure go the complicated way :)

```
$mergedarray = array_map('array_merge', $firstarray, $secondarray);
```

Basically "merge the arrays of each index".

`array_merge_recursive` doesn't work because number index are not considered as associative key. So it just push the value instead of merging them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
$firstarray = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Smith'),
    1 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane Doe')         
);

$secondarray = array(
    0 => array('email' => 'john@smith.com'),
    1 => array('email' => 'jane@doe.com')
);
```

**Use simple foreach loop**

```
$res = [];
foreach($firstarray as $k=>$record){
  $record['email'] = $secondarray[$k]['email'];
  $res[] = $record;
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

**OR use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)  function**

```
$res = array_map(function($a,$b){
  return ['id'=>$a['id'],'name'=>$a['name'],'email'=>$b['email']];
},$firstarray,$secondarray);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

Comment: No need for a handmade callable, `array_merge()` already exist.

Comment: Yes. Agree with you but answer is correct and working then why down vote? You can definitely raise your point in your answer.

Comment: downvoted because it's unnecessarily complicated ^_^ I'll change the downvote to an upvote if you edit of course.

Comment: You have already given answer bro. So no need for edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $firstarray = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Smith'),
    1 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane Doe')
 );

  $secondarray = array(
    0 => array('email' => 'john@smith.com'),
    1 => array('email' => 'jane@doe.com')
  );

 foreach($firstarray as $key1 => $value1)
 {
   foreach($secondarray as $key2 => $value2)
   {
        if($key1 == $key2)
        {
            $firstarray[$key1]["email"] = $value2["email"];
        }
    }
 }
 print_r($firstarray);
```